# how to change the logo href when onclick the logo

Tags: php

i am asking for the how to change the href of the logo when onclick on it and back to the admin page or homepage based on the user login which is admin or user.

If the login person is user, when the user click on the logo will bring user back to the user homepage.

If the login person is admin, when the admin click on the logo will bring admin back to the admin page.

```
<!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->
          <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="index.php" >
        <div class="sidebar-brand-icon  ">
```

[logo for the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlysO.png)

i m asking for the if else statement for the href like if user is admin the logo will change the href and else will go user homepage.

Comment: Personally, i think this isn't good practice to disable buttons for users without privileges. a good way to do this in my opinion is to modify the endpoint of the button using a session cookie or something to check for the user's privileges, so if they don't have access to it, they just see a page that says they don't have access to it. additionally, you can just not render the button for users without appropriate access.

Comment: alright then. just wanted to share some thoughts.